# at what point in time does this.getServletName() begin to work and what is the rationale

Tags: java, constructor

I find that `this.getServletName()` fails in a constructor but works in a method.  Note `getServletName()` is provided by the parent of the parent.  This was observed in Google App Engine.  What is the rationale for `this.getServletName()` behaving this way?

(The failure is a null pointer dereferencing but I note that `this` is not null at the time so I think the null may be something internal to the JRE.  Furthermore and as expected, assignments of the sort `this.myprivate = myconstructorarg;` do not produce a null dereferencing in constructors.)

```
public class ResponderServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
        public ResponderServlet() 
        {
            String ss = this.getServletName();  // RUNTIME ERROR
        }

        public void doMethod(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws IOException 
        {
            String ss = this.getServletName();  // WORKS WELL
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getServletName()` method will work after the web container calls the `init(config)` method. You should likely put your initialization logic there instead of the constructor. E.g.:

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    super.init(config);
    String ss = this.getServletName();
    // put your logic here instead of constructor
}
```

Comment: OK, so with these comments in mind I realized that getServletName() is not the same as xxx.getClass().getName().  The former has a lifecycle as pointed out by Suresh and that needs to be understood and naturally somethings simply will not be ready.  By contrast the latter is something Java can do early.

Answer (score 0):

`getServletName()` method belongs to ServletConfig interface.

You should know when the ServletConfig object is created, which will then give proper value for `getServletName()`.For this learning of servlet lifecycle is important.

```
If an instance of the servlet does not exist, the Web container
  -  Loads the servlet class.
  -  Creates an instance of the servlet class. // not available here.
  -  Initializes the servlet instance by calling the init method. // available here.
   Initialization is covered in Initializing a Servlet.
```

The servlet container will inject the servletConfig object(by reading web.xml ,once deployment is done) in to the init method of servlet, so it is available in init and not at the constructor level.

ServletContainer

```
GenericServlet

 /**
  *
  * Called by the servlet container to indicate to a servlet that the
  * servlet is being placed into service.  See {@link Servlet#init}.
  *
  * <p>This implementation stores the {@link ServletConfig}
  * object it receives from the servlet container for later use.
  * When overriding this form of the method, call 
  * <code>super.init(config)</code>.
  *
  * @param config           the <code>ServletConfig</code> object
  *                 that contains configutation
  *                 information for this servlet
  *
  * @exception ServletException     if an exception occurs that
  *                 interrupts the servlet's normal
  *                 operation
  *
  * 
  * @see                UnavailableException
  *
  */

     public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    this.config = config;
        this.init();
   }
```